# Window Clion have no hint for standard libarary

Tags: c++, settings, clion

When I use Clion to wirte c++ code, I want to check class and method in standard libaray like `string` , `iostream` or what else, and when I want to use `"cout"`, I found that their is no hint(`I press alpha "c" on the keyborad and clion doesn't show complete cout`). and I also use Ctrl+Mouse Click to click , Clion tells me that like the picture below:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFiET.png)

and Here is my CMakeList.txt
[CMakeList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H4hL.png)

I also check my toolchain in seeting:
[tool chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39AOu.png)

Answer (score 0):

oh，I found the problem where is, the path of project shouldn't contain any chinese.